# Why is the Question about a range of possibilities too broad?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, flags

I just came online a few min ago and the first thing I found was [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/225941/what-can-i-craft-with-these-weapons-in-tf2) on hold because it's too broad and I can't figure out the reason for that.

I don't play TF2 however the question is about all possible combination of things that can be created which I think isn't too broad but the answer could be too large.

So my question is: How is a question about a specific set of Items flagged as too broad?

Thanks for answers and good morning community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not closed for being 'too broad', it's closed as '*primarily opinion based*'.

This was the original text:

> **What can I craft with these weapons in tf2?**
>
> So I have some spare weapons that are taking up space and/or I just don't use them. I have a second wrangler, razorback, jarate, mantreads, warrior's spirit, natascha, eyelander, ambassador, powerjack,and the axtinguisher. What can I craft with these weapons **that will be worth-while**? (this is not an opinion-based question as "worth-while" means like **statistically great weapons** NOT BY ANY MEANS is that opinion)

It's likely the close-voters closed this because of the two bolded lines above. I would've voted to close this had I seen it as well. The problems that I see are:

- There is no clear-cut definition of what a 'worthwhile' TF2 weapon is.

  - A weapon that I like, might be hated by someone else. For example, I dislike using the Dead Ringer, but a lot of people really like it.
- What is 'statistically great' will vary greatly based on:

  - The playstyle of the person wielding the weapon
  - The map it is being used on
  - The game-mode being played.
  - Whatever patch Valve is pushing out this week changing how weapons work. Again.

A bit more on that last point: Weapons in TF2 are fairly well balanced. There are positives and negatives for using every weapon, and this is constantly tweaked by the developer Valve to maintain the balance. So any game-breakingly-awesome weapon will only be that way until Valve find a way to nerf it.

The rest of the question is actually OK. It's very specific to the OP and probably  not very useful to others, but otherwise it's fine. The OP removed the last two points, and the question is now receiving reopen votes.

Comment: [*Prepares for a barrage of downvotes for speaking ill of the Dead Ringer*]

Comment: Well in the original text I would agree with the close votes however it's edited and I vote for reopening because now he just asks for a full list

Comment: @Nitro.de - yep, that's what edits are for :-)